# Assign Word Object to Variant Variable in VBA

Tags: vba, object, ms-word, variant

My aim is to create an array of various global templates which I define in a table. My macro reads the table. If the name specifies an available template my array should hold the object. If the template can't be found the array should hold the name that couldn't be processed. *ThisDocument* is of docm type. It's assigned to Sfs(0) as the default. Here is an excerpt from my code.

```
Private Sub TestSetSfs()
    Dim Sfs() As Variant
    SetSfs Sfs
    Debug.Print Sfs(0).Name
    Debug.Print VarType(Sfs(0))             ' returns vbString
End Sub

Function SetSfs(Sfs() As Variant) As Long

    Dim Tbl As Table

    ReDim Sfs(20)                           ' max 20 references
    Set Sfs(0) = ThisDocument

    Debug.Print Sfs(0).Bookmarks.Count      ' works as expected
    Debug.Print VarType(Sfs(0))             ' returns vbString
    Debug.Print GetTextTbl(Tbl, Sfs(0), "SomeName")
End Function

Function GetTextTbl(Tbl As Table, Doc As Document, Tn As String) As Boolean
    GetTextTbl = True
End Function
```

My problem is with the line *Set Sfs(0) = ThisDocument*. In the next line of the test procedure Sfs(0) works correctly as an object, permitting a Bookmarks.Count. It's also shown as an object in the Locals window. However, the function GetTextTbl rejects it as "ByRef argument type mismatch" which it doesn't do when replaced with *ThisDocument* in the function call. This prompted me to look at its VarType which returns VbString instead of vbObject.

Let me add that I already have this idea working in Excel (with addins) but I need an equivalent in Word where I think the global template would meet my requirements if I could assign objects to the Sfs() variant. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Remove your 2 debug.print lines and use this instead - `Debug.Print Sfs(0).Bookmarks.Count` - and that should prove that it's assigning the document object as you want.

Comment: Perhaps you are right but why does *GetTextTbl(Tbl, Sfs(0), TnRef)* - in the next line after the bookmark check (which works for me, too) - give a "ByRef argument type mismatch" error and *GetTextTbl(Tbl, ThisDocument, TnRef)* doesn't? Function *GetTextTbl* expects *Doc As Document*. It was this that prompted me to look at the VarType. I'll do some more testing. Thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: I have expanded the question as you suggest.

Comment: It probably needs to be casted from a generic object to an actual document object, but as a workaround, you can just change the function definition to `Function GetTextTbl(Tbl As Table, Doc As Variant, Tn As String) As Boolean` and it will work. That doesnt exactly answer your question, but it works if you put `MsgBox Doc.Bookmarks.Count` in your `GetTextTbl()` function.

Comment: I found another option for a workaround - use `Object` instead of `Variant` - `Dim Sfs() As Object` and `Function SetSfs(Sfs() As Object) As Long` - then you can use `Function GetTextTbl(Tbl As Table, Doc As Document, Tn As String) As Boolean`

Comment: And finally, everything I have read on the subject online says that you cannot convert a `Variant` to an `Object` in VBA, so use one or the other as they both seem to do what you want. I guess it would depend on what other routines these functions need to be used in conjunction with as they would have to match as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would need to be casted from a `Variant` to an `Object`, but everything I have read on the subject online says that you cannot convert a `Variant` to an `Object` in VBA.

Your alternatives are to stick with using a `Variant` in all places (instead of the `Document` object) or stick with using an `Object` in all places, as they both seem to provide the functionality you need in this example.

So either change it to this (to use the variant method):

```
Function GetTextTbl(Tbl As Table, Doc As Variant, Tn As String) As Boolean
```

Or change both of these to this (to use the object method):

```
Dim Sfs() As Object 

Function SetSfs(Sfs() As Object) As Long
```

Using it as an `Object` in all cases makes the most sense to me, as then you can use your original declaration of your `GetTextTbl` function as:

```
Function GetTextTbl(Tbl As Table, Doc As Document, Tn As String) As Boolean
```

And then your intellisense will work inside of that function. Just make sure you do not pass an object to it that is something other than a Word Document or you will get an error.

Comment: I think you have answered my question exhaustively. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit of a late answer but the solution to your problem is to use a collection rather than an array.  Collections (or Scripting.Dictionaries) are a more natural way to work with objects.

```
Private Sub TestSetSfs()
    Dim Sfs As Collection
    Set Sfs = New Collection
    SetSfs Sfs
    Debug.Print Sfs.Item(1).Name
    Debug.Print VarType(Sfs.Item(1))             ' returns vbString
End Sub

Function SetSfs(ByVal Sfs As Collection) As Long

    Dim Tbl As Table

    
    Sfs.Add ThisDocument

    Debug.Print Sfs.Item(1).Bookmarks.Count      ' works as expected
    Debug.Print VarType(Sfs.Item(1))             ' returns vbString
    Debug.Print GetTextTbl(Tbl, Sfs.Item(1), "SomeName")
End Function

Function GetTextTbl(Tbl As Table, Doc As Document, Tn As String) As Boolean
    GetTextTbl = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @freeflow. In fact, your response is very well timed. I had forgotten about the problem. Even my question seemed strange to me. But for the past 6 months or so I have been working to finalize this 2018-project that had been prompting it and I do have a problem with the changing ActiveDocument. So, your suggestion might come in handy.